# Changing an Int to a CGFloat in Swift to return heightForRowAtIndexPath tableview function

Tags: ios, swift, int, cgfloat, heightforrowatindexpath

I am sure that I am missing something really simple, but I just can't get it to work.

I will try to explain better what I am doing to try to help others if they have this same issue.

This was my function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return (count * 40 + 75) as CGFloat
}
```

The above function doesn't work. Thanks to the help I received, I found that this is the way to do it:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(count * 40 + 75)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? The question is pretty concise and well written

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is simple:

```
let i = 123 // an Int
let f = CGFloat(i) // a CGFloat
```

If you command-click on `CGFloat` then you'll see all its initializers:

```
init(_ value: Float)
init(_ value: Double)
// ... many more, and finally:
init(_ value: UInt)
init(_ value: Int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5, there is a handy constructor for this purpose, [init(integerLiteral:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cgfloat/1455362-init)

```swift
let cgFloat = CGFloat(integerLiteral: intVar)
```