# iOS: one itemSpace of uicollectionView is 1px but another is 2px, I want the two all 1px?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView， in 1 and 2 section I want every itemSpace and lineSpace to be 1px, but the second itemSpace is always 2 px, this is screenshot, I have set collectionView's backgroundColor red, it looks more clearly.

this is screenshot

[image]

I set the minimumLineSpacing, minimumInteritemSpacing and itemSize like this:

```
 - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
        {
            float sortaPixel = 1.0/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

            NSLog(@"minimumLineSpacing%f", sortaPixel);

            return sortaPixel;
        }

        - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
        {
            float sortaPixel = 1.0/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

            NSLog(@"minimumInteritemSpacing%f", sortaPixel);

            return sortaPixel;
        }

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        if(ISBIND){
            return CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, finalTopheight);
        }
        return CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, defaultTopheight);
    }


    //This is the calculation process
    float sortaPixel = 1.0/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    NSLog(@"sizeForItem%f", sortaPixel);

    CGFloat itemW = (self.collectionView.frame.size.width - sortaPixel * 2)/3.0;

    CGFloat itemH = 106;

    return CGSizeMake(itemW, itemH);
}
```

anyone can help me, give me some ideas, I am very grateful.

Comment: Actually its repeating the border in next cell means the first left border of 1px and second right border of 1 px = 2 px .

Comment: what should I do?@RaheelMateen

Comment: Actually i never use this delegate method to draw a border a simply draw border with uiview . if you need so i will share my code  ????? @rose

Comment: OK, I wanna see your code, thank you.

Comment: please accept my answer if its help you. Thanks.

Comment: should it help ??? @rose

Answer (score 0):

> A combination of having to describe the problem here and a bit of
>   subsequent thought caused me to realize that although
>   minimumInteritemSpacing is a CGFloat it doesn't make sense to pass it
>   fractional values and its behaviour when you do so is undefined.
>
> This is because, on devices where there's a 1:1 point to pixel ratio,
>   there is no such thing as half a pixel. It just so happened that in
>   some cases it behaved as I expected and thus blinded me to the real
>   (and rather obvious) problem.

Hopefully reading this can help others quickly realize the mistake.

See the post to know Float and CGFloat,

[Changing an Int to a CGFloat in Swift to return heightForRowAtIndexPath tableview function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079416/changing-an-int-to-a-cgfloat-in-swift-to-return-heightforrowatindexpath-tablevie)

Comment: how can I resove the problem?

Comment: Put a contant value as CGFloat and return it. Than observe that does it varies or gap remains same. Like return constant one pixel as CGFloat object

Answer (score 0):

```
// AdselecterNamed top border in a view
+ (void)addTopBorderWithColor:(UIView *)view color:(UIColor *)color andWidth:(CGFloat) borderWidth {
    UIView *border = [UIView new];
    border.backgroundColor = color;
    [border setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, borderWidth);
    border.tag = 1000;
    [view addSubview:border];
}



// Add bottom border in a view
+ (void)addBottomBorderWithColor:(UIView *)view color:(UIColor *)color andWidth:(CGFloat) borderWidth {
    UIView *border = [UIView new];
    border.backgroundColor = color;
    [border setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.frame.size.height - borderWidth, view.frame.size.width, borderWidth);
    border.tag = 1001;
    [view addSubview:border];
}

// Add left border in a view
+ (void)addLeftBorderWithColor:(UIView *)view color:(UIColor *)color andWidth:(CGFloat) borderWidth {
    UIView *border = [UIView new];
    border.backgroundColor = color;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, borderWidth, view.frame.size.height);
    [border setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
    border.tag = 1002;
    [view addSubview:border];
}

// Add right border in a view
+ (void)addRightBorderWithColor:(UIView *)view color:(UIColor *)color andWidth:(CGFloat) borderWidth {
    UIView *border = [UIView new];
    border.backgroundColor = color;
    [border setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
    border.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width - borderWidth, 0, borderWidth, view.frame.size.height);
    border.tag = 1003;
    [view addSubview:border];
}
```